# prime addition program looping

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program which determines the sum of the first 1000 prime numbers.

```
def main():
    sum = 0
    numberOfPrimes = 0
    divcount = 0

    for number in range(1,10000):
         for divider in range (1,(number/2) + 1):
            if number%divider == 0:
                divcount += 1

            else:
                divcount += 0

        if divcount == 1:
            sum += number
            numberOfPrimes += 1
            break

        else:
            sum += 0
            numberOfPrimes += 0
            break

        if numberOfPrimes == 1000:
            print sum

    return 

main()
```

It doesn't print anything. There must be something wrong with the loops, how I wrote them probably. It seems to only do the first number then stop.

Comment: Get rid of the 'break' statements. Maybe add one just after printing the sum. Also, you don't need the 'else' parts at all.

Comment: Also, 'divcount' should obviously be reset to 0 at the beginning of each iteration of your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement exits the current loop.  Read up on how it works...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm

For a working example of prime summations see here... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37550/summation-of-primes-takes-forever

Answer (score 0):

When you use `break` you are exiting your 'for' loop. Just get rid of these and you are good!
**Edit:** You need to reset `divcount` at the top of your 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the break statements otherwise the program will stop running after the first number. `break` exits the current loop.

You should also add a `break` statement after you printed the sum of the first 1000 primes.

Finally the `divcount` variable needs to be reset for every new number.

`for number in range(1,10000):
      divcount = 0`

I tested your code with those changes and it worked fine.